# How do I create a file with utf-8 format in lua?

Tags: html, file, utf-8, lua

I've created a file with the following code in lua:

```
local f = io.open("./data/myfile.html", "w") 
f:write(text) 
f:close()
```

String is stored in the file is Persian. When the file is opened letters are illegible. Like the screenshot below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP8xi.png)

How I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua doesn't care about encoding. If your Lua source texts are already in utf-8, then you should just add "meta" tag in html "head" section.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

If your html version is earlier than html5, then use older construct:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```